# EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification / EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification Stops Firing

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, observers, mfi, eaaccessory

I'm writing an app communicates with an external device connected on the lightning slot. I utilized the EAAccessory framework to communicate with the device. Then, I've added the following code in my ViewDidLoad to monitor the connection/disconnection of the accessory.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(accessoryDidConnect:)
                                             name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(accessoryDidDisconnect:)
                                             name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];

[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
```

With the above code, I was able to received notifications on the *accessoryDidConnect:* and *accessoryDidDisconnect:* selectors when I attached/detached the device. But after some time, an intermittent behavior, I stop receiving notifications from the selectors above though I haven't called the *removeObserver* nor *unregisterForLocalNotifications*. Please let me know if I missed anything that can trigger this issue.

Comment: I recently stumbled upon something similar, could you find the cause ?